# How shall I prove this Stochastic integral equation?

Tags: stochastic-integrals

I want to prove
$$
\int_0^T B_t^2 dB_t = \frac{B_T^3}{3} - \int_0^T B_t dt
$$
by the definition of Ito integral.

I have tried this so far. Given a partition $0=t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n=T$, I want to have
$$
\sum_i B_{t_i}^2 (B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i}) -  \sum_i \frac{B_{t_{i+1}}^3 - B_{t_i}^3}{3} + \sum_i B_{t_i} (t_{i+1} - t_i) \to 0
$$
as the partition becomes finer and finer.

But I am stuck here. How shall I proceed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like it follows from a direct application of the Ito-Doeblin formula $$f(B_T)-f(B_0) = \int_0^T f'(B_t) dB_t + (1/2) \int_0^T f''(B_t) dt$$ with $$f(x)=x^3/3$$.

Comment: @Flounderer: Thanks! I hope to prove it by definition.

Comment: Do you mean that you should prove it by definition? Otherwise, it is a very simple example for the application of Ito formula and @Flounderer told you.

Comment: @Ilya: Yes, I should. Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Could you calculate the expectation and variance of the expression you've obtained?

Comment: @Ilya: Thank you! For the LHS, its expectation is 0 and its variation is complicated. So what is the idea here?

Comment: The only method we used to prove result of Ito integration be definition - verifying that expectation is zero and variance tends to zero with $\max\Delta t_i\to 0$.

Comment: @Ilya: Thank you! By Ito integral definition, the convergence is in terms of $L^2$ norm. Is it equivalent to expectation cvging to 0 and variance also cvging to 0?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1871/discussion-between-ilya-and-steveo)

Answer (score 1):

use the following identity:
$3\cdot B^{2}_{t_{i}}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})=B^{3}_{t_{i+1}}-B^{3}_{t_{i}}-(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})^{3}-3\cdot B_{t_{i}}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_{i}})^{2}$.